# Do I need to separate /var and /tmp from the root partition on AWS EC2?

Tags: linux, partitioning, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A result of an audit check on the Amazon Linux AMI gave a number of recommendations on the file structure, for example the need to have the root and /var and /tmp on different partitions.

Is this still advisable practices in the public cloud world or hang over from on-prem hardware and VM infrastructure?

Comment: I don't see why it would make much difference? btw you may be looking for https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks I'll ask there.